Why is the sidestick on an Airbus so stiff?
Recently, I was so very kindly allowed to test the control surfaces on an A321. When I moved the sidestick on the Captain's side, I realised that it's FAR stiffer than my regular HOTAS stick at home. Does anybody know why it's so stiff?

Prevents bumping, maybe?

Welcome to Aviation SE! I agree with Darth's guess, but I'm not expert so I won't answer.  I will say: power steering in your car is regularly designed to self-damp as the speed of the vehicle increases, this is because even small adjustments to a vehicle in motion can result in large forces being applied to the object and its contents. I suspect this is a safety feature, meant to ensure that the captain is able to make minute changes in control input and has to work hard to make larger inputs.

lovely, thank you both ever so much

Because the force feedback from your hand is much more accurate than the position feedback. So with higher feedback forces you would know what sort of input the hand is giving without looking at it, not so with the low force levels of a games sidestick.
Way more info about the force feedback in this answer, about a stick that in first instance did not move at all: the F-16 stick. Incredibly high g-forces trying to drag the underarm of the pilot sideways, creating an ever larger input...Force feedback is what is required, as much as possible, which you get with a high spring stiffest or even a fixed stick.
